# Is there a text on Apache Spark that attempts to be as comprehensive as White's Hadoop: The Definitive Guide'?

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop, apache-spark

Tom White's 'Hadoop: the Definitive Guide' has become a popular guide to the entire Hadoop ecosystem and earned a reputation as providing both a broad survey, as well as covering individual aspects of Hadoop in decent depth. Has anyone thus far attempted to provide the Spark equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Learning Spark: Lightning Fast Big Data Analytics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do) is a fairly comprehensive book covering the core concepts as well as the higher level components involved in the Spark stack. This is the book recommended by Databricks for their Spark Developer Certification as well.

If you are interested more about the use cases built using Spark, I suggest [Advanced Analytics with Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035091.do?green=FDE26D1E-4F6A-5328-9E23-46715C3B56EB&intcmp=af-mybuy-0636920035091.IP)